# LibGDX ColorAction.restart() doesnt work

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to loop the ColorAction animation.
Here is my code:

```
ColorAction action = new ColorAction();
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;

@Override
public void create () {

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    action.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    action.setEndColor(Color.GOLD);
    action.setDuration(5);



}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int fps = Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond();
    curFrame++;
    if (curFrame == fps*5) {
        action.restart();
        curFrame = 0;
    }

    action.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(action.getColor());
    shapeRenderer.rect(100, 100, 40, 40);
    shapeRenderer.end();



}
```

But this is not working properly. It's just plays the animation once and stops.
Can somebody explain me what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

After a couple of changes:

```
ColorAction actionBtG = new ColorAction();
ColorAction actionGtB = new ColorAction();
SequenceAction sequenceAction;
RepeatAction repeatAction = new RepeatAction();
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
Color blue = new Color(Color.BLUE);

@Override
public void create () {

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
    actionBtG.setColor(blue);
    actionBtG.setEndColor(Color.GOLD);
    actionBtG.setDuration(5);

    actionGtB.setColor(blue);
    actionGtB.setEndColor(Color.BLUE);
    actionGtB.setDuration(5);
    sequenceAction = new sequenceAction(actionBtG,actionGtB);

    repeatAction.setAction(sequenceAction);
    repeatAction.setCount(RepeatAction.FOREVER);
}

@Override
public void render () {

    repeatAction.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(blue);
    shapeRenderer.rect(100, 100, 40, 40);
    shapeRenderer.end();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the call to `setColor` tells it what instance of Color to modify, so you don't want to pass it a pseudo constant like Color.BLUE or you will be modifying the "constant" itself. The LibGDX color class is mutable, so even though `BLUE` is `static final`, it can still be modified. You need to create your own Color instance for use with the action and pass that in.

```
myColor = new Color(Color.BLUE);
```

To do a color cycle, you need two ColorActions (one for each of the two colors you switching between), and they need to be in a SequenceAction together. Both of them should be set to your same Color instance. And then if you want it to cycle multiple times, wrap the SequenceAction in a RepeatAction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just did the following steps:
Created 2 colors: `Color blue = new Color(Color.BLUE);
 Color gold = new Color(Color.GOLD);`
Then I've set the Color option of both ColorAction: `actionBtG.setColor(blue); actionGtB.setColor(gold);`
Created SequenceAction: `sequenceAction = new SequenceAction(actionBtG,actionGtB);`
And created RepeatAction with FOREVER flag:
`repeatAction.setAction(sequenceAction);`
But it still doesnt work properly. I think I'm still doing something wrong. I'm kinda new to libGDX and to java also, but really want to understand this thing.

Comment: They both need to point to the same color instance. Don't create a blue and a gold. Just create one color that both actions will modify. Use that color object on your shape renderer.

Comment: Ah, thought that I got it, but it's still doesnt work.
Added some info in the first post.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved? ... I had the same problem a few minutes ago... The problem is, that the startcolor, in your case blue, has the same color like the endcolor, if the action is over. So you can't see any action! I solved this problem by creating a new instance, but I think, reset the start color should also work. I will try it later.

This means for you: Try to set the color again, wenn you will restart your action!

EDIT:
I replaced the ColorAction with my own class now:

```
public class ColorTransitionAnimation extends TemporalAction {
private final Color start = new Color();
private final Color end = new Color();
private final Color animatedColor = new Color();
private RepeatType repeatType = RepeatType.REVERSE;

public enum RepeatType { REVERSE, RESTART }

public void setRepeatType(RepeatType repeatType) {
    this.repeatType = repeatType;
}

protected void update (float percent) {
    float r = start.r + (end.r - start.r) * percent;
    float g = start.g + (end.g - start.g) * percent;
    float b = start.b + (end.b - start.b) * percent;
    float a = start.a + (end.a - start.a) * percent;
    animatedColor.set(r, g, b, a);
}

@Override
protected void end() {
    super.end();
    if(repeatType == RepeatType.REVERSE)
        setReverse(!isReverse());

    restart();
}

public Color getAnimationColor () {
    return animatedColor;
}

public void setStartColor (Color color) {
    start.set(color);
}

public void setEndColor (Color color) {
    end.set(color);
}
```

}